# Create variables on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Im creating code snippets dynamicly:

```
var gg = setInterval(function() {
    if($('p:visible').length > 0) {
        $('p').trigger('click') ;
        clearInterval(gg);
    }
},500);
```

The code works. The problem is that I create the same code snippets with different selectors:

```
var gg = setInterval(function() {
    if($('input:visible').length > 0) {
        $('input').trigger('focus') ;
        clearInterval(gg);
    }
},500);
```

So when I put(create) these codes together, the whole thing goes in to some loop and it doesn't work anymore, take a look at this example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3C4v/)

The problem is that I assign the same variable (gg) to the codes. So my question is: How do I create different variables every time I create these code snippets? I tried some things with `var x=x++` but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? I can't see what your general usage pattern is going to be.

Comment: Never mind case closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the snippets in anonym wrapper functions so that the variable gg is not global anymore:

```
(function(){
    var gg = setInterval(function() {
        if($('input:visible').length > 0) {
            $('input').trigger('focus') ;
            clearInterval(gg);
        }
    },500);
})();

(function(){
    var gg = setInterval(function() {
        if($('p:visible').length > 0) {
            $('p').trigger('click') ;
            clearInterval(gg);
        }
    },500);
})();
```

(These Functions are executed automatically...)

Comment: Great! Would you be so kind to accept my answer as Correct?!

Comment: Yes sure. Maybe you are new to Stack but it takes a while before someone can accept anwser, I think about 8 min or so, so next time just be patient..:-)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways of accomplishing what you want to do (dynamic variables). The first is evaling a string.

(There are a ton of articles out there that will explain why this is bad. But, for the sake of being complete, I'm providing this example...maybe as an example of what not to do ;)

A function that creates variables based on a string you pass in, and then using that eval'd variable would work. Something like:

```
function varMaker(str){
    // Nothing fancy...
    var token = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() * Math.random(10));

    // Defining variable with no var for global scope (bad)
    return eval(str + '_' + token + ' = undefined;');
}
```

Here's a quick/dirty fiddle example (no function maker, just an eval'd string): http://jsfiddle.net/D3wZ7/

The second, cleaner approach is using square bracket notation (and what I would recommend). Something like this:

```
window['gg' + randomized_string] = setInterval(..)
```

Note: Once you've defined the variable, you can reference it as you normally would as such:

```
window['my_cool_variable' + 1] = "stack";
alert(my_cool_variable1); //alerts "stack"
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmGH5/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
var gg= [];
gg[0] = setInterval(function() {
    if($('p:visible').length > 0) {
        $('p').trigger('click') ;
        clearInterval(gg[0]);
    }
},500);

gg[1] = setInterval(function() {
    if($('input:visible').length > 0) {
        $('input').trigger('focus') ;
        clearInterval(gg[1]);
    }
},500);
```

so go on like this way. You can create lots of by using array.

Comment: Except that it is not working. `Syntax Error` on `var gg[0]`, leave the `var` off. ;)

Answer (score 0):

in that other snippet change 
var gg =... 
to var hh =... 
and then clearInterval(hh)

Comment: I need a piece of code that does just that for me...I'm creating the snippets dynamically with php, so I **can't** change the variable manually...Thats the point of my question........

Comment: if you do it with php then in php change the names of these variables, if you have some for loop then just put numbers after variable names gg1 gg2

Comment: Question. Why do you create js code snippets in php?

Comment: What does it matter..?